# Invalid conversion from const, but wasn't declared as const

Tags: c, constants

I declared the following `char*` and tried to pass it to a function that requires a `char *` as the 3rd argument:

```
char *echo;
prompt = ssh_userauth_kbdint_getprompt(primarySession, 0, echo);
```

However, I get the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

I also tried declaration as `char echo;` and the passed argument as `&echo`.  But I don't really need the value that this function changes in `echo`. So I wanted to pass NULL, but I guess I expected that to be a `const`.  I also tried [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906595/is-const-a-lie-since-const-can-be-cast-away):

```
char echo;
prompt = ssh_userauth_kbdint_getprompt(primarySession, 0, (char *)(&echo));
```

Still no success. Suggestions?

Comment: Forget about `echo`. It is not about your `echo`. It is about `prompt`. How's your `prompt` declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the declaration of that function:

```
const char *
ssh_userauth_kbdint_getprompt (ssh_session session, unsigned int i, char *echo)
```

Thus it is `prompt` that needs to be a `const char *` instead of a `char *`.

Comment: Ah yes, I was distracted away from even looking at the return type since the error was claimed to have occurred at column 63, directly over top `&echo`....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with return value of that function, not any of its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is not where you think, but in the return type. I'd guess that your `prompt` variable is `char*` where the function returns a `char const*`.