# 'const' methods in template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, object, constants

I've just started reading about template classes in C++ and I have come across some syntax I'm unaware of.
A class method is prototyped as:

```
template <class Type> class Range {
            ....
        bool Below    (const Type& value) const;
            ....
}
```

and defined as:

```
template <class Type> bool Range<Type>::Below(const Type& Value) const {

    if (Value < Lo) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand the meaning of the 'const' flag after the method inputs have been listed?
I understand there use when put before an input but not after.
Cheers,
Jack

Comment: Nothing to do with templates. When constructing a [testcase](http://sscce.org) you'd have found that this is simply a feature of member functions.

Comment: const can sometimes be confusing unless you know WHY you're using it. In addition to the good answers here, read up on programming defensively, [const-correctness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `const` member functions a *top level* const qualifier is applied to each member of the class, unless the member is marked as `mutable` (which means never `const`).

You can also have `volatile` member functions and both `volatile` and `const`.

Note, that for pointers and references the behaviour may be surprising:

```
struct X {
    int a;
    int* pa;
    int& ra;
    X() 
        : a(1)
        , pa(&a) 
        , ra(a)
    {}

    void foo() const {
        *pa = 2; // Ok, this is the pointer being const, not the value being pointed to.
        ra = 3; // Ok, this is the reference being const, not the value being referenced.
        a = 4; // Error, a is const
        pa = &a; // Error, pa is const.
    }
};
```

Below is how *top level* `const` qualifier is applied:

- `int` becomes `int const` - a constant integer.
- `int*` becomes `int* const` - a constant pointer, not `int const*` - a pointer to constant.
- `int&` becomes `int& const` - a constant reference, not `int const&` - a reference to constant. Applying `const` to references does not do anything, because they can not be changed to refer to another object anyway.

Another way to think about this, is that in non-const member functions `this` has the type of `X* const`, whereas in const member functions `this` is `X const* const`. Note how `this` *pointer* is always constant.

Answer (score 3):

Const after a method means that the method itself is constant, and in fact will have a constant 'this' pointer. In basic terms it means that method is not allowed to make changes to the state of the class (member variables). This allows the compiler to optimize on this fact, and tells other developers that the method will not be making state changes.

There are ways to get around this rule in C++, such as the 'mutable' keyword and const_cast, but really you shouldn't try and break const correctness unless you really, really know what you're doing.

Comment: I'm not sure if the compiler is allowed to do optimizations, as we're allowed to have `mutable` members.

Comment: The compiler will do optimizations unless 'mutable' is used. Compilers are smart enough to know when a class has mutable members and when it does not. Trust me, compilers optimize against const methods.

Answer (score 3):

This means the method is const. The method cannot change the state of the object it is called upon. If you change variables in this method, you will get a compiler error.

Only methods declared const can be called on a const object, because they are guaranteed to not change it.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers implicitly pass a pointer to the object as an argument of a non-static member. It is named `this` in the function definition. The qualifier `const` means that this pointer `this` has the qualifier `const`. That is it is applied to the pointer `this`.

Comment: And that would make pointer `this` const (i.e. `X* const`), not the value pointed to. Note that `this` is always const, you can not reassign it. My favourite interview question is `typedef char* P; typedef const P Q; typedef P const V`, what are `Q` and `V`?

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin Maybe my description is not clear but I meant const SomeClass *.

Comment: Compilers apply cv-qualifiers on the right, in fact, so what you said is `SomeClass* const`. This is the reason some people write `int const` instead of confusing `const int`.