# Using sort for a class vector with private variables

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector

i have a class

```
class Studentas
{
 public:
 static const int CPaz=10;
 private:
 string pavarde, vardas, grupe;
 double paz[CPaz],   // paþymiø masyvas
 np;          // paþymiø kiekis
 double vidurkis;
 double STsk;
 public:
 Studentas(): pavarde(""), vardas(""), grupe(""), np(0), STsk(1),vidurkis(0)
 { }
 double imtinp(){return np;}
 double imtipaz(int i){return paz[i];}

 void Deti(string pav, string vard, string grup, int np, int pz[],double vid);
 void grupeDETI(string grp,double vidurk){grupe=grp;vidurkis+=vidurk;}

 double iv(){return vidurkis;} <---------------------------------------THE ONES IM USING
 void isvestiVID(){vidurkis/=STsk;}
 void pridetiSK(){STsk++;}

 string ig(){return grupe;} <---------------------------------------THE ONES IM USING
 string Spausdinti(int i);
 string SpausdintiGrupes();
};
```

the bool i was using bool

```
myfunction(Studentas const &d1,Studentas const &d2){return (d1.iv() > d2.iv() || d1.iv()==d2.iv()     && d1.ig() < d2.ig());} 

vector<Studentas> grupe;(with whatever length)

sort(grupe.begin(), grupe.end(),myfunction);
```

and i get an error, " cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Studentas' to 'Studentas &' "

EDIT : i use void functions to get my variables.

EDIT2: thanks for all the help, i think i'll just bubble this one out.Dont have the time to waste, thanks again for the help.

EDIT3: dun goofed on my operator overlays, the method below works.

Comment: Where exactly is the error occuring?

Comment: Make `ig` and `iv` `const` so you can use those with `const` objects. You might also want to implement `>`, `<`, and `==` instead of needing to provide access to private members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark your methods as `const`:

```
double iv() const {return vidurkis;}
```

This way you'll be able to call them on `const` objects, which is what `d1` and `d2` are.

All methods that logically don't need to modify the object should be marked `const`.

Comment: this seems to break my program :C

Comment: Agree with @Luchian [this is worth a read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness).

Comment: @jonasrudzionis meaning?

Comment: i start getting library errors, as in:
'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'Studentas'

Comment: i've done the same thing with container class but vector just screws me with that sort

Comment: @jonasrudzionis that's a different error, please post a new question with the new code (stripped down to the minimum that reproduces the new error)

Comment: Hey, figured i'll just post here, the problems was that my overlayed opperator was edited in a way that was glitching out, I was just a little bit careless while writting.Your thing worked when implemented for some stuff later, thanks a lot.