# Pass By Reference Using *this from const member function doesn't compile?

Tags: c++

I'm following along some sample code, but I'm getting an error from it that I don't know how to fix properly. 
I'm getting an error passing *this as a reference. Here's the relevant code:

```
//ShadeRec.h

class World;

class ShadeRec
{
public:
  World& w;

  ShadeRec(World& wr)
}

ShadeRec::ShadeRec(World& wr) : w(wr) {}

//World.h

#include "ShadeRec.h"
#include "Ray.h"

class World
{
public:
  World();
  ShadeRec hit_bare_bones_objects(const Ray& ray) const;
}

ShadeRec World::hit_bare_bones_objects(const Ray& ray) const
{
    ShadeRec sr(*this);
    //Do stuff with sr
    return sr;
}
```

The error is happening in hit_bare_bones_objects where I declare ShadeRec sr(*this); The error is:

> 1>  error C2664: 'ShadeRec::ShadeRec(const
>   ShadeRec &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const World' to 'World
>   &'
>   1>  Conversion loses qualifiers

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: ShadeRec(const World & wr)

Comment: This trades one error for another. Now I get: 1> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const World' to 'World &'
1>  Conversion loses qualifiers
1>  error C2439: 'ShadeRec::w' : member could not be initialized

Comment: `public:  const World& w;` then. Do you intend to changethe World in ShadeRec?

Comment: The example code doesn't explain the intention specifically, but I'm guessing they do want the ability to change ShadeRec::w. However, what you suggest seems perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"What is the correct way to do this?"*

You either need to define the constructor with a `const` reference parameter

```
  ShadeRec(const World& wr);
        // ^^^^^
```

or declare your

```
  ShadeRec hit_bare_bones_objects(const Ray& ray); // <<< no const
```

member function in the `World` class non `const`.

Which is the *correct way* depends on `//Do stuff with sr` includes operating on a non `const` `World` instance, or not.

Class function members declared as `const` anyway only have access to a `const` `this` pointer, which can only be dereferenced as a `const` reference in turn.

---

A 3rd option is to use a `const_cast<>` when interacting with the interface of the other class. That's not necessarily recommended, and you should really know what you're doing. It's of a similar danger level, like using `reinterpret_cast<>`<sup>1</sup>:

```
ShadeRec World::hit_bare_bones_objects(const Ray& ray) const {
    ShadeRec sr(*const_cast<World*>(this));
              // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^
    //Do stuff with sr
    return sr;
}
```

---

1) <sub>I'm using `const_cast<>` occasionally, when I'm annoyed by other API's (I can't change or patch), that don't get [`const` correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness) right. I still don't want let to creep in their faults into my code (as long I'm sure about doing so).</sub>

Comment: Thanks. I went with declaring the hit_bare_bones_objects method as non const. I was not aware that it made *this constant until you wrote it. A lot of the answers say to use ShadeRec(const World& wr); but this trades one error for another since ShadeRec::w cannot be initialized when the constructor is changed in this way.

Comment: @elveatles If you use `const` for parameters and class function members, you need to do it consequently and concisely. Introducing `const` correctness for an existing code base, that didn't care much about, can become a quite tedious task quickly. I agree for such case, sometimes simply leaving it alone (beyond better knowledge), is the better and more pragmatic decision. If you're building a code base from scratch, keep `const` correctness wherever it should occur.

Answer (score 1):

`ShadeRec::ShadeRec` is saying "the world `wr` you give me is non-constant; no guarantees it will remain unchanged". `ShadeRec sr(*this);` is saying "here's a world that is constant, i.e. mustn't be changed". That's a conflict. To solve it, either make `ShadeRec(World& wr)` (and `World& w`) constant, or make `World::hit_bare_bones_objects` non-constant.

Answer (score 0):

Make your parameter declaration of `ShadeRec` constructor const:

```
ShadeRec::ShadeRec( const World& wr)
```

When you define `hit_bare_bones_objects`, it is marked as `const`, which means that the function is not allowed to change the state of `this`.  If you passed `*this` by non-const reference in the constructor of `ShadeRec` it could allow `ShadeRec` to violate that const declaration.  Hence, you pass by const reference.
You could also remove the `const` from `hit_bare_bones_objects` and then you could leave the `ShadeRec` constructor as is.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In your method:

```
ShadeRec World::hit_bare_bones_objects(const Ray& ray) const
```

You have told the compiler that you will not modify any of the objects in `World`.

You will need to pass the `*this` as a constant reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are passing `*this` inside a `const` method. So this is also const here, and can be used only in const context.

So, if you want to keep this method const then you should, make:

```
ShadeRec::ShadeRec(const World& wr) : w(wr) {}
                   ^^^^^
```

but also `World& w;` inside ShadeRec should be changed to `const World& w;`, which might be not what you want.