# C text parser does not identify word

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to do a simple parsing of text with a C program. A function I have written is supposed to check the buffer that has a line of text saved into it and see if this line contains a particular word at BOL.

The input arguments are:

- `size`: the sizeof(word), calculated before the function is called.
- `buf`: the buffer containing a line from the text being parsed.
- `word`: the word that the function looks for at BOL.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int strchk(int size, const char buf[1024], char *word) {
    char a[size];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        a[i] = buf[i];
    }
    if (strcmp(a, word) == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

The problem is that for some reason, a word is not being recognized. Previous words have been correctly identified by the same function. Below are two contexts wherein the function is being called, the first one results in a correct identification, the second does not, while the text contains both words at the start of different lines within the text.

```
char c[] = "|conventional_long_name";
if (strchk(sizeof(c), buf, c)) {
    fputs("    conventional_long_name: \"", stdout);
    getdata(buf, c, sizeof(c));
}

char d[] = "|official_languages";
if (strchk(sizeof(d), buf, d)) {
    fputs("    religion: \"", stdout);
    getdata(buf, d, sizeof(d));
}
```

When I check string a in the `strchk()` function for size first, it gives me a size of 20, but if I make it print out the string it tells me it is in fact `|official_languagesfici`. When you count the number of characters it's just as long as the previously mentioned `|conventional_long_name`, which would suggest some parameter from that function call is at play in the next function call, I just can't figure out where I have made the mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you set the null terminator in `a` in `strchk`?

Comment: omg, you're right I completely forgot -_- thanks so much though for pointing it out, it fixed the problem right away.

Comment: Btw, I think you are looking for `strncmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the null terminator of the `a` array in the function `strchk`.

Do it using

```
a[size - 1] = '\0';
```

after the `for`-loop.

---

Notes:

- since you don't modify the string `word` in the function `strchk`, declare the parameter `const`. [`const`-correctness is important!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness)