# Why are const pointers not used more often in C

Tags: c, constants

It's hard to see code snippets and real code using const pointers in C.

By example:

```
FILE *fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode);
```

My question is. Why it appears to me, I may be worg in affirming this, that people usually don't use const pointers even when would make sense to use it? 
In my example fopen may have const pointers in both parameters.

I know how to use const and I know how it works. My question is more from an software engineering perspective and why people who write big libraries don't use it so much. Is there a reason not to use const pointers in professional code? Usually I only see a lot about const in books and code snippets.

Comment: use const whenever you can. But I suppose that we cannot rewrite the whole C library here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of 'const' for function parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters)

Comment: My question is. Is there a reason not to use const pointers in real and professional code?

Comment: Backwards compatibility with pre-ANSI C?

Comment: I'd say `const` does get used a lot, because it can be very useful, and many programmers appreciate that.  It's not used everywhere it could be, it's true, because sometimes it's significantly more work, especially since when you start making some things const, you typically have to make lots more things const to compensate, and sometimes, one of them can't be, so you're stuck.  (I think this is what people sometimes call "const poisoning".)

Comment: @Rodolfo, nowdays there is no reason.

Comment: In your example, it would make no difference. Making `filename` and `mode` `const` is an implementation detail, not part of the API. So why add a pointless keyword to the declaration?

Comment: In your example they are not const pointers. They are pointers to a const char

Comment: To make const pointers you write "char * const filename"

Comment: Some useful commentary at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness, if you haven't seen it.

Comment: @melponeme: of course it makes a difference: if the arguments are not `const` qualified, passing `const` strings triggers a well deserved warning. As a matter of fact, string literals should be `const` and most compilers can be configured to make them const. `-Wwrite-strings` for both gcc and clang does that.

Comment: In fact, the declaration of `fopen` from the C standard is `FILE *fopen(const char * restrict filename, const char * restrict mode);`; it seems like there are commenters implying that standard C has some other definition.

Answer (score 4):

Early versions of C (well before the first ANSI standard in 1989) did not support `const` at all.   So functions in the standard library, like `fopen()` were originally specified without the `const` qualifier.

In some professional settings, using old code and old compilers is still sometimes required for reasons of backward compatibility (although such cases are getting rarer as time advances, they still do exist, and for various reasons will continue to exist for some time).   This requires that libraries used in those settings remain backward compatible.

Unless there is a specific constraint like this, it is preferable to write modern code using `const` appropriately (for example, to indicate that a function does not change an argument passed by pointer).   That provides more opportunities to detect programmer error (e.g. a function that changes an argument, which the caller assumes is unchanged).

A common reason for code that doesn't use `const` is programmer (or, worse, customers) caring more about quick delivery - getting code delivered that compiles and passes a few test cases without error is priority number 1, but getting the code working properly in every possible contingency is considered much less important (or someone else's problem).  In such a setting `const` causes more compilation errors (e.g. due to a function changing something tagged `const`) and therefore requires more effort and time to get the code compiling.   Whereas omitting `const` means the code compiles more easily.   Removing all instances of `const` in a code base (unless it uses third party libraries that are not available as source) is quite easy with modern text editors and IDEs - and can superficially cause the number of compilation errors to drop.    Conversely, it is more difficult to identify all the places in code where `const` is useful, and the most likely immediate reward for increasing usage of `const` in a code base is needing to do more work to fix code that then doesn't compile.

In other words, the benefits of `const` are not immediate, so do not matter to developers/managers/customers with a short term "deliver or die" mentality, who will not have to subsequently fix the problems they leave behind.

Comment: Quick fix for die hard obsolete compilers: `#define const`.  There is no decent reason to not use `const` qualified pointers.  Declaring `const` local variables and arguments such as `const int  i = 3` or `const char * const filename` is much less useful and leads to unnecessary clutter.

Comment: You're thinking in the wrong direction.  If the code only targets a hardware platform for which there is one compiler that doesn't support `const`, things like `#define const` give no benefit.   Most such examples are in a regulated application domain, so it would be necessary to also document a justification that such a macro doesn't change the behaviour of any code in the system.   Forcing people in tight regulatory domains to use `const` when it actually has no meaning to their compiler, will make the regulatory burden of that software higher.

Comment: the `#define const` would only be defined if the compiler does not support the `const` keyword.  As long as the code does not use `const` as an identifier nor elide type information as in `const a = 1;`, it should be OK to remove the effect of `const` with the preprocessor. A command line definition `-Dconst=` would have the same effect without the need to patch the source files.  C compilers that do not support `const` are bound to be so out of date that the language they implement is a distant cousin of C.  I wouldn't want to work in such a constrained environment...