# Why do we not use const more often?

Tags: c, constants

It is common to see the keyword `const` with pointers :

```
void function(const char *string)
{
    const char *other_string = "some string";
}
```

But why do not we use const every time we declare a variable that we will not change ? It is rare to see :

```
void function(const int i)
{
    const double j = 1.2;
    // i and j will not be changed in this function
}
```

I am trying to understand why we do not use `const` more often, is it always a good thing to use it when we can, or not ?
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness?noredirect=1&lq=1) seems to answer YES, but in reality this doest not seem to be the case ...

Comment: First the linked url talks about C++ which is definitely different. If you have to declare `constant expression` through your code you should use `#define` because `const` just tells that the value is read-only. `Define`s are more common in C language.

Comment: Cultural thing, mostly.  An accidental assignment in an if() expression is no longer a problem, compilers warn about that.  If you *need* it then you have another problem, the function body is probably too large.  To each his own.

Comment: `const` is extremely useful in interfaces, less so elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases it no longer makes a difference.

Often enough the compiler will be able to deduce that the variable is actually read only, and treat it as a constant during optimization.

Either way, you usually use `const` consequently on things like `const char *string` in order to avoid accidentally modifying the parameter.

Since all parameters are passed by value, this isn't something which can't happen for an integer. Only for pointers the pointer itself is the value.

Actually, `const char *string` isn't fully constant either yet. Only the `char`s the pointer is pointing to is, but the pointer as a variable isn't. It would only become when specifying it as `const char * const string`. Now the `string` variable is completely constant for the scope of the function.

Comment: Nitpicking: Arguments in C are _always_ passed by value.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you give, I would *always* say

```
void function(const int i)
```

in a situation where the role of `i` is to parameterise the behaviour of the function -- which is almost always. If I change `i` in the body of the function, I have either made an error, or written something which another person will find hard to understand later.

Intentionally modifying the value of `i` in the function isn't as "dangerous" as modifying a entity through its pointer -- it won't create side-effects outside the function. I guess that's why most developers don't feel the pressure to define primitive paramters as `const`. I maintain, however, that it is a sensible thing to do, if one cares about long-term maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, the parameter is passed by value, making it `const` basicly has no meaning. `const` is most handy when passing parameters by reference.
There is another problem with `const` known as "const poisoning". Consider the following:

```
int foo(char * str, int n)
{
    ...
    bar(str);
    ...
}
```

If we make `str` to be `const`, we must then ensure that bar also takes a `const` etc. (which can affect multiple files and modules). This is especially painful if you're editing old and inconsistent code (not always the case, but should be considered).

Comment: I sympathise with this problem. However, perhaps an alternative approach is to use `const` where it seems to be appropriate, and use temporary objects to wrap calls to dodgy old code: `char *str_temp = strdup(str); old_function(str_temp); free (str_temp);` I quite understand what a drag this is, however.

Comment: Pretty much depending on the code itself, not always the case, but I mention it as something that may be worth considering.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't really disagreeing with you. It's difficult to know how much to fight old, nasty code, in my experience.