# Can't use "const reference of a function object" in a function parameter

Tags: c++

I'm learning function objects, and I'm trying this by writing *std::transform* myself. I created an **Increment** struct. I will create an object from this struct and use it as a **function object** in the parameters of my transform function.

This is my **Increment struct**:

```
template<typename T>
struct Increment
{
    T by_what;
    void increment(T& item)
    {
        item += by_what;
    }
    void operator() (T& item)
    {
        increment(item);
    }
};
```

This is my **transform free function**:

```
template<typename T>
void transform(std::vector<T>& container, Increment<T> inc)
{
    for(auto& item : container)
        inc(item);
}
```

But I don't want to make a copy of the **inc** object and I don't want to change anything about it. That's why I wanted to write `const Increment<T>& inc` in the parameter but compiler didn't let me.

This is my **main function**:

```
int main()
{
    auto v1 = std::vector<int>{10, 20, 30};
    auto inc = Increment<int>{5};
    transform(v1, inc);
}
```

This is the error:

***week5-app2.cpp:50:9: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const Increment'
week5-app2.cpp:73:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'transform' requested here
week5-app2.cpp:14:10: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Increment', but method is not marked const***

Could you explain why writing as const reference is problematic in this case? Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: *"but compiler didn't let me"* - Please include the error message that this generated.  Also, how are you calling `transform`?

Comment: btw you can change your transform to `template<typename T, typename C>
void transform(std::vector<T>& container,const C& c)` to make it more generic. You wont have to change anything else (only the fix from the answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compiler does quite a good job at explaining the issue:

> candidate function not viable: `'this'` argument has type `'const Increment'`, **but method is not marked `const`**

`const` object can only use `const` member functions. Change your functions to

```
template<typename T>
struct Increment
{
    T by_what;
    void increment(T& item) const //const here
    {
        item += by_what;
    }
    void operator() (T& item) const //and here
    {
        increment(item);
    }
};
```

You should always use `const` by default to all member function unless they are modifying any data members. This will make keeping [const correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness) much easier.